# How do I read this proportion?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

Geneticists say that the color of Italian squash should follow the $12:3:1$ ratio. A group of researchers collects the following information: White 155, yellow 40 and green 10. Are these data consistent with the hypothesis of the geneticists?

I have to perform a chi-square test, but I need the expected frequencies which are obtained with the following formula

$e_i=nπ_i  $ where $n$ is the sample size and $π_i$ is the assumed proportions

What I don't understand is how to occupy $12:3:1$, is 12% or $\frac{2}{3}$ or $\frac{\frac{2}{3}}{1}$ ?

Comment: The proportions of white, yellow, and green are $\frac{12}{12+3+1}, \frac{3}{12+3+1}, \frac{1}{12+3+1}$ respectively.

Comment: They mean that the ratio of white to yellow squash is $12:3$ and that of yellow to green is $3:1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of observations is $n = 155 + 40 + 10 = 205$.  The theoretical or hypothesized proportions are $\pi_1 = 12/16$ white, $\pi_2 = 3/16$ yellow, and $\pi_3 = 1/16$ green; hence the expected frequency of white is $205(12/16) = 153.75$, and so forth.